# Spring Boot - Best way to return JSON data

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

Actually I am building a REST API and there are many differents ways to return the JSON data. But I want to know a good one that can be scalable in time and taking care of many to many relationships, and deep relations (Article -> has Category -> has Department -> etc..)

Some few options:

1) DTO pattern and building it manually taking care of the "fields" parameter of the request.

2) The `@JsonView(View.Example.class)` at Entity class.

3) The default JSON serialization on Spring Boot (Jackson).

I think the more scalable option is the 1st, where I can handle the many to many relations and other stuff... What do you think?

Comment: What are your intentions ? Do you want to build just a RESTfull backend that communicates with a client FE or you want to make a Web service ?

Comment: I want to make a restful json web service. In the early feature we will need to build the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to mix both option 1 and 3.

You should have a converter to convert an Entity into a Response DTO. There you can map all your deep relations. Just make sure that you have all your deep relations loaded before the converter kicks in to prevent multiple database reads.

When you're finished, Jackson will do the job.

Comment: Yeah, now I am mixing it, but I see that spring boot docs has many others solutions, and maybe I am implementing in a wrong way. Or in real world app does not works properly, because of many to many associations, or business logic in the middle..